# why is linking to libOpenCL.dylib failing with undefined symbol

Tags: c++, c, macos, linker-errors, pocl

I am trying to build the pocl library on MacOS

System:

```
MBP 16" 2019
Intel i9, AMD Radeon 5500m
Mac OS 12.4
using bash, instead of zsh
llvm from home-brew, -version 14
```

I have the following in my .bash_profile to setup the build environment

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH
export CC=clang
export CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang
export CXX=clang++
export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
```

I go and clone the repo with git, cd into the source directory, mkdir build

Then in `build/` run:

`cmake .. -DENABLE_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DENABLE_ICD=OFF`

The config seems to work and then when I run make everything builds, and gets to the end but then gives me the following error:

```
[100%] Linking C executable poclcc
clang-14: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clBuildProgram", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
      _poclu_load_program_multidev in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clCreateCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _poclu_get_any_device2 in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
      _poclu_get_multiple_devices in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clCreateContext", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
      _poclu_get_any_device2 in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
      _poclu_get_multiple_devices in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clCreateContextFromType", referenced from:
      _poclu_create_any_context in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clCreateProgramWithBinary", referenced from:
      _poclu_load_program_multidev in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clCreateProgramWithIL", referenced from:
      _poclu_load_program_multidev in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clCreateProgramWithSource", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
      _poclu_load_program_multidev in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clGetDeviceIDs", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
      _poclu_get_any_device2 in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
      _poclu_get_multiple_devices in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clGetDeviceInfo", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
      _poclu_load_program_multidev in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clGetPlatformIDs", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
      _poclu_create_any_context in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
      _poclu_get_any_device2 in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
      _poclu_get_multiple_devices in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clGetProgramBuildInfo", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
      _poclu_show_program_build_log in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clGetProgramInfo", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
      _poclu_show_program_build_log in libpoclu.a(misc.c.o)
  "_clReleaseContext", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
  "_clReleaseProgram", referenced from:
      _main in poclcc.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I checked and libOpenCL.dylib was successfully built in the `pocl/build/lib/CL/` directory.  Just as a check, I tried compiling `clinfo` with a direct link to this library and it gave me the same set of error messages shown above.

Running `nm libOpenCL.dylib | grep clBuildProgram` prints the following:

`0000000000013850 t _clBuildProgram`

So its in there, but it is a local text section symbol.  I don't actually know what that means though, and if that means it should work, or should not work.  I don't actually understand what the problem is here or why this linking is failing, or what to do about it.  Looking for some guidance on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the lower case t is that the symbols are local, i.e. not externally visible to linking programs. Upper case T would be externally visible.

POCL has a number of configuration options, not all of which are documented in the Build section of the docs.  The `VISIBILITY_HIDDEN` option is on by default unless the `ENABLE_PROXY` option is on.

In `build/`, running:

`cmake .. -DENABLE_ICD=OFF -DVISIBILITY_HIDDEN=OFF`

and then:

`make`

the compile succeeds to the end.  Then in `build/lib/CL/` running:

`nm libOpenCL.dylib | grep clBuildProgram`

now prints:

`0000000000013790 T _clBuildProgram`